# Automate printing PDF from Google Sheets with no buttons

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

I am printing a pdf file from Google sheets via [Google Cloud Printer](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/).

It works but **I need to automate the procedure so that I click the button on sheets and automatically a pdf is created and get printed.**

**And no need to print by clicking the button on the dialog.**

I managed to set this up with just 1 button click (initial button on sheets) but it works only up to creating a pdf file. The printing jos is not being added to the cloud.

Though when I print by clicking the button I have a window where I choose a printer or Google Drive and then click "Print".

The code for printing button:

```
gadget.setPrintButton(document.getElementById("printBtn"))
```

So I want to avoid clicking all that buttons and print by default to the printer.

My code on a server side:

```js
   //move chart to a separate sheet and open print dialog
   function moveChart() {  

       //move chart to object sheet
        var printSheet = ss.moveChartToObjectSheet(chart)        

        //activate object sheet
        printSheet.activate()

        var pdf = createPDF()

        var printForm = openPrintForm()            
        }


   //create pdf out of sheet
   function createPDF() {

        //folder to save pdf to
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RseEezmGT2gSBS9rgdV0E2ggRD5O6dyu")

        var pdf = ss.getAs("application/pdf").setName("Chart")

        //create pdf in the folder
        var file = folder.createFile(pdf)
        }


   function openPrintForm() {

        var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("print").evaluate().setWidth(800).setHeight(600)
        var title = html.setTitle("Printing...").getTitle()

        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, title)
        }
```

Html code:

```html
   
   window.onload = function() {
        
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WYAKlW_LU3XI_UGWXHr3B0FH_D1Wpj3t-ImPQ2LYU3c/edit#gid=2503262"
    
        var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
        
        gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Print sheet", url);
        }
```

p.s. Google documentation of printing is here //https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget